# Question on elementary calculus

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Given a function $g(x)$ which has a derivative $g'(x)$ for all $x$ satisfying 
>   $g'(0) = 2$ and 
>   $$ g(x+y) = e^x g(y) + e^y g(x) $$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. How to show that 
>   $$
> g'(x) + g(x) - 2e^x = 0\ ?
> $$

Answer (score 2):

I think the question has a typo. From $$g(x+y) = e^x g(y) + e^y g(x)$$by differentiating with respect to $y$ we obtain$$g'(x+y) = e^x g'(y) + e^y g(x)$$by adding them up we have$$g(x+y)+g'(x+y)=2e^yg(x)+e^x(g(y)+g'(y))$$now if we put $y=0$ in the above equation we will have$$g(x)+g'(x)=2g(x)+e^x\Big(g(0)+g'(0)\Big)=2g(x)+2e^x$$whic finally yields to $$g'(x)-g(x)-2e^{x}=0$$

Comment: differentiating wrt y of $ g(x+y)$ will gives $g'(x + y) ( dx/dy + 1) $ isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but in case that $x$ is a function of $y$. Here, $x$ and $y$ are independent variables.

Answer (score 1):

Divide an equation with $e^{x+y}$ then we get $${g(x+y)\over e^{x+y}} = {g(y)\over e^{
y}} +{g(x)\over e^{x}}$$ Now let $f(x)={g(x)\over e^{x}}$ so we have $$f(x+y)= f(x)+f(y)$$

So this is Cauchy equation and since $f$ is continuous we have $f(x)=ax$ so $g(x)=ax\cdot e^x$. Since $2=g'(0) = ae^0+a0e^0$ we have $a=2$ and thus  $$g'(x)+g(x)-2e^x = 2e^x+2xe^x+2xe^x-2e^x =0$$